# Reading text files from local directory

Tags: java, android

I´m trying to read text file and display it in WebView. This is my method :

```
public static String readFileAsString(String filePath) {

        String resultString = "";
        File file = new File(filePath);

        if ( file.exists() ) {

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

            try {

                fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                char currentChar;

                while (fileInputStream.available() > 0) {

                    currentChar = (char) fileInputStream.read();
                    resultString = resultString + String.valueOf(currentChar);

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("", e.toString());
            } finally {
                if (fileInputStream != null)
                    try {
                        fileInputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException ignored) {
                    }
            }
        }
        return resultString;
    }
```

and in the same activity I call it :

```
textView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

textView.loadData("<p style=\"text-align: justify\">"+  readFileAsString(finalPathText), "text/html; charset=windows-1250", "utf-8");
```

In my app, everything is displayed but before every special character it writes A with ^ . example: `Žilina` writes as `^AŽilina`.

Could anybody helps me?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you seem to be confused as to whether the encoding is windows-1250 or utf-8. It cannot be both. That is the most likely cause of your problem. You'll have to figure out the actual encoding and treat the files as such.

Comment: I change it into: textView.loadData("<p style=\"text-align: justify\">"+  readFileAsString(finalPathText), "text/html", "UTF-16");but it doesn´t work

Comment: It doesn't work like that, you can't just put something there. You have to know the original encoding of the file and read it in in that encoding.

Comment: I know, I tried to save my file with that encoding and it is worse , Instead od Žilina is written A..A%ilina :/ Isn´t it possible that there is a mistake in my readFileAsString method?

Comment: What happens if you print the file in your console instead of displaying it in your app? How is your Java process started? I know for one that Eclipse doesn't use utf-8 or utf-16 by default. I don't have access to Eclipse right now but try to search for encoding in the settings.

Comment: I recommend reading http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html. It might clear up a lot.

Comment: When I use UTF-8 in android studio and also ina my text file and print it into system it prints: I/System.out: The University of Å½ilina

Comment: So try to go with 1 encoding everywhere, otherwise you're bound to run into problems. If you have no control over the encoding of the text files you read you'll at least have to read them in with the correct encoding and display them as such. Did you read the article I linked?

Comment: Yes I read it so i´m going to change some thing in my code so I hope It helps

Comment: You're welcome to upvote my answer in case this helped you :)

Comment: it does not wok :( I choose ANSI encoding, I use it in saving my file and also in Android studio and that sign appears but with some unwilling character ex: AŽilina instead of Žilina

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to change the encoding from windows-1250 to utf-8/utf-16, because encoding windows-1250 unsupported special character.

Comment: And don´t you have any idea how to do that? I tried almost everything :/

Comment: Problem is encoding, but I haven't more info.

Comment: @NataliaD try this `textView.loadData("<p style=\"text-align: justify\">"+  readFileAsString(finalPathText), "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");` or `textView.loadData("<p style=\"text-align: justify\">"+  readFileAsString(finalPathText), "text/html; charset=windows-1250", "windows-1250");`